# Python Kernel crashes after closing an PyQt4 Gui Application

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

Ok here is my problem:

I want to create a PyQt4 Gui, which can be executed from a python console (tested with IDLE, Spyder Console and IPython Console) and then allows the user to change and view variables. After closing the app the user should be able to do further work with the variables in the console. But by closing the Gui the Kernel crashes and it is not possible to make any new input to the console.

I'm working with Python 2.7 and PyQt4. I am using the following code to start an close the application:

```
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainApp=plottest()
MainApp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Kernel crashes? Do you mean kernel panic occurs? Are you sure? It is also very difficult to answer your question without the rest of the code.

Comment: Having a similar problem. "It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console."

Comment: I think that hdunn's answer should be accepted, as it is a better practice solution than the one provided by Gabriel Asqui (even though that one does fix the problem in some situations!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easy solution here https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/45h05k/solved_kernel_crashing_when_closing_gui_spyder/

only put

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=0           #This is the solution
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainApp = Dice_Roller()
    MainApp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What a bizarre problem and unlikely solution. Thanks for the link!

Comment: This doesn't work for me - the second time I run the code the GUI appears to be drawn differently, and the third time I run it the kernel still dies

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is:

1. Check that there isn't already a QApplication instance when trying to create a new one
2. Ensure that the QApplication object is deleted after it's been closed

(See [simple IPython example raises exception on sys.exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888045/simple-ipython-example-raises-exception-on-sys-exit))

```
# Check if there's a pre-existing QApplication instance 
# If there is, use it. If there isn't, create a new one.
app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
if not app:
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

# Ensure that the app is deleted when we close it
app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)

# Execute the application
MainApp = plottest()
MainApp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Using this code you can rerun the application as many times as you want in IPython, or anywhere else. Every time you close your Qt application, the app object will be deleted in python.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you mean a kernel crash. Rather, I think you are talking about exiting the python console. This is caused by `sys.exit(app.exec_())`. For example try (for example in spyder) the following two codes:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QtGui.QWidget()
widget.setWindowTitle('simple')
widget.show()

#sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here you should get an empty window and the python console will stay alive. The second one, where `sys.exit(app.exec_())` is included, will exit the python console at the end  and the window disappears:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QtGui.QWidget()
widget.setWindowTitle('simple')
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know the issue and solution. None of the above worked for me. Currently I am coding in the spyder GUI and running on "cmd" by giving 'python' command. In CMD, it is working fine.

Update the solution if I get it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

hdunn's answer worked for me. Have deleted sys.exit() to avoid exiting the application totally. Performing the first step alone, as suggested by others in github forum, solved part of the problem but window never showed up, nor any error message. Performing the second part solved everything like a charm! Thans, hdunn!

```
# Check if there's a pre-existing QApplication instance 
# If there is, use it. If there isn't, create a new one.
app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
if not app:
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

# Ensure that the app is deleted when we close it
app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)

# Execute the application
MainApp = plottest()
MainApp.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that python console closes (its not kernel crash). For example in Spyder python icon on top of console window becomes grey and you cant do anything besides running another console.

Anyway, you should write `app.exec()` instead of `sys.exit(app.exec())`.

I believe `sys.exit(app.exec())` passes exit code to console and closes it. Using simple `app.exec()` won't close console.

Concluding your code should look like:

```
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainApp=plottest()
MainApp.show()
app.exec_()
```

I hope it helps.