# Python kernel dies for second run of PyQt5 GUI

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, pyqt5, spyder

- Using Spyder in Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit) Windows package. qt: 5.6.0
- For first run, GUI window opens as expected
- For 2nd run, nothing opens, and receiving **Kernel died, restarting** log message.

**gui1.py:**

> ```
> import sys from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
>
> app = QApplication(sys.argv)
>
> w = QWidget()
>
> w.resize(250,150) w.show()
>
> #sys.exit(app.exec_()) 
> app.exec_()
> ```

**IPhython log:**

```
runfile('F:/work/ws_python/TestProj1/gui1/gui1.py', wdir='F:/work/ws_python/TestProj1/gui1')

runfile('F:/work/ws_python/TestProj1/gui1/gui1.py', wdir='F:/work/ws_python/TestProj1/gui1')

Kernel died, restarting

Kernel died, restarting

Kernel died, restarting
```

Why kernel dies for 2nd run and how to solve it?

> (Doing the same even using #sys.exit(app.exec_()) as last line.)

Comment: Qt may not like you creating more than one `QApplication` object in the same process. You can use `QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()` to get the application instance if one was already created. [Code example](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/IPython%20Kernel/gui/gui-qt.py).

Comment: Could you provide an example for my case? It does not work for me.

Comment: I think the important bit is to get the existing instance of the application if it exists: `app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()`. Then, if it doesn't exist, create a new application: `if app is None: app = QtGui.QApplication()`.

Answer (score 20):

This code fixed the problem, thanks for the hint.

```
app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 4):

This works better for the kernel died, restarting error.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication

#app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app = QCoreApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the above solution worked but only as long as the window-close button (from the Window decoration) was used to close the main window. But the problem still was present when the program was terminated from a GUI signal handler, reacting e.g. to a button being clicked. After much fiddling, I learned that a safe enough way for terminating in this situation is as follows:

```
def safeExit(self):
    """exit the application gently so Spyder IDE will not hang"""
    self.ui.deleteLater()
    self.ui.close()
    self.ui.destroy()


... self.ui.Button2.clicked.connect(self.safeExit) ...
```