# PyQT5 - Warning to use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D for quitting the application in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, pyqt5

I am currently learning PyQt5 and I have encountered [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094086/python-kernel-dies-for-second-run-of-pyqt5-gui) and solved it using the solution explained there, but since then, I am seeing this warning

```
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 0


/home/aditya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2971: UserWarning: To exit: use 
'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

Now, I don't know if this warning could be harmful or not. But how do I fix this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [simple IPython example raises exception on sys.exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888045/simple-ipython-example-raises-exception-on-sys-exit)

Answer (score 0):

you are facing this error because you are using in your code sys.exit() function. it is implemented from pyqt4 to pyqt5 which is latest one! i suggest you to do not use sys.exit instead of this you can use app = QApplication(sys.argv) app.exec_() app.quit() for terminating your window.